# Dropdown List Items Are Multiplying on clicking Gridview Select Button Each Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Here is my Page Load Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "SELECT BOOK.book_name,BOOK.price,BOOK.author,BOOK.publisher,BOOK.isbn,BOOK_APPROVAL.status,BOOK_APPROVAL.cat_id FROM BOOK INNER JOIN BOOK_APPROVAL ON BOOK.book_id = BOOK_APPROVAL.book_id";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, obj.connect());

        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        ds1.Clear();
        DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

        string str1 = "SELECT cat_id,cat_name from CATEGORY";
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(str1, obj.connect());
        da1.Fill(ds1);

        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds1;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "cat_name";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "cat_id";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
```

I have a dropdownlist, gridview with select button and a approve Button on the same page. When I click select button its values are displayed in series of textboxes and then i select a item from the dropdownlist. Its datavaluefield is assigned to a variable using the below code:

```
 SqlCommand ddl = new SqlCommand("select cat_id from CATEGORY where cat_name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem + "' ", obj.connect());

catID = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.ExecuteScalar());
```

Finally when i click approve button values of all textboxes are inserted into the table where ID= dropdownlist.datavaluefield.

My problem is that when i click on the gridviews select button each time ,my dropdown list values are displayed Multiple times.

So, tried `ds1.Clear()` and `DropDownList1.Items.Clear();` in page load, and it solved that problem, but it resets my Datavaluefield to '1'. So i can't insert into the table using selected datavaluefield.

So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to wrap the code in `Page_Load` in a `!Page.IsPostBack`-check:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // code here that should be executed only at the first time 
        // and not on consecutive postbacks
    }
}
```

The items are stored in `ViewState` by default in ASP.NET.

Comment: I wonder how much rep has been generated in the ASP.NET tag from answers like this one (regarding people not knowing to wrap their initialization / databinding code in `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`) =)